# Delay function of jquery to load?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to delay blocking by 2 seconds while executing this code. How can I do that ? I tried setTimeout but it did not worked.

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').value='Saving...';
$('#Block').block({message:'Please wait...',css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) here, like this:

```
//block, what you currently have:
$('#Block').block({message:'Please wait...',css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }}); 

//unblock in 2000ms, or 2 seconds
setTimeout(function() { $('#Block').unblock(); }, 2000);
```

If you're dealing with an UpdatePanel then I would look at the [`end_Request` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx), and actually unblock/reenable when the request finishes.

Comment: Nick the unblock is inside endRequest of PageRequestManager. I set it over there but it won't work.

Comment: It is unblocking but just in a snap. I think there is some other problem maybe the script is broken.

Comment: @Popo - Is you block element inside the update panel? in that case it'll be getting replaced with the request.

Comment: Nick, yeah the div is inside the update panel, source of problem=)

Comment: @Popo - Then you need to either move it outside the panel, or call `.block()` with a 0 fade-in time to get the illusion it never went away just before the `.unblock()`.

Comment: thanks Nick you were spot on. The div inside update panel was the main problem.

Comment: Hi just a little question, how can I disable the button for 2 seconds also. $('#Block').block({message:'Please wait...',css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }});   
                        document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').disabled=true;
                        document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').value='Saving...';